# Python ldif3 parser and exception in for loop

Tags: python

From site: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ldif3/3.2.0

I have this code:

```
from ldif3 import LDIFParser
from pprint import pprint

parser = LDIFParser(open('data.ldif', 'rb'))
for dn, entry in parser.parse():
    print('got entry record: %s' % dn)
    pprint(record)
```

And now, reading my file `data.ldif` I have exception in `parser.parse()`.
Question is how to catch this exception and allow for loop to go to next record (continue)?

Trackback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ldif.py", line 16, in <module>
    for dn, entry in parser.parse():
  File "/home/dlubom/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ldif3.py", line 373, in parse
    yield self._parse_entry_record(block)
  File "/home/dlubom/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ldif3.py", line 346, in _parse_entry_record
    attr_type, attr_value = self._parse_attr(line)
  File "/home/dlubom/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ldif3.py", line 309, in _parse_attr
    return attr_type, attr_value.decode('utf8')
  File "/home/dlubom/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xb3 in position 6: invalid start byte
```

Comment: File `data.ldif` probably not utf8 encoded. According to [this](https://github.com/xi/ldif3#unicode-support) you can set encoding in constructor: `LDIFParser(..., encoding=...)`

Comment: Ok, but its not solving my problem, there could be any other exception.

Comment: What exceptions? In ldif library or in your code?

Comment: In ldif lib, in parser.parse()

Comment: Without `data.ldif` I can't reproduce a problem. Did you set encoding to `None`?

Comment: I set encoding to None. It should help on exception with decode. But I wory about any other exceptions that may happend. data.ldif is very big file.

Answer (score 0):

i think it's not possible to handle exceptions in such case because they happend before / during the variable assignment.

BTW probably want to use the attribute:

> strict (boolean) – If set to False, recoverable parse errors will
> produce log warnings rather than exceptions.

Example:

```
parser = LDIFParser(ldif_file, strict=False)
```

https://ldif3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

That helped me parsing an invalid ldif file containing commas inside CN attributes.